# mule4 dataweave 2.0 write csv file with only headers

Tags: java, mule, mule4

In dataweave2.0 if payload is empty it should print only headers with pipe seperated. i have tried below code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv separator='|', header=true
---
[{
      field1: "",
      field1: ""

}]

Output:
field1|field2|field3
|||

Desired output is only headers:
field1|field2|field3

Please guide
```

Comment: The problem is your example is giving empty values for the fields so there is an empty line to output

Answer (score 0):

%dw 2.0

### output application/csv separator='|', header=false

[{
      field1: "field1",
      field2: "field2"

}]

Try this it may works for you...

Comment: this removes the header. the question asks how to only print the header if content is empty?